# When we say our ASP.NET core Web API is a Microservice?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

Scenario 1: I have a Web API build in ASP.NET Core framework and deployed at Service Fabric Cluster. Will it come under bracket of Microservice ?

Scenario 2: I have developed a middle layer of Web APIs build in ASP.NET Core deployed at Service Fabric Cluster. It work as a middle layer for some UI and third parties.  Will my API come under Microservice category?

Comment: start here, I'd say and see if whatever you have matches the definition of a microservice: https://microservices.io/

Comment: `Microservice` is a fashion term. It used to be called SOA until that name was subverted by vendors. In fact, Wikipedia calls it [a variant of SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices). Loose coupling, independently deployable, bounded context, isolated development  etc are *ALL* core concepts of SOA

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu that's also a description of SOA

Comment: The real difference between SOA and Microservices is a preference for smaller service sizes and the use of newer protocols. It has little to do with the stack you used or the deployment environment. Do you have *multiple* services? Can they be developed and deployed independently? Are they isolated from each other, even at the data level? Are they doing a specific, well defined job, ie are they bounded?

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with @TomTom.

We need to understand that there is a difference between a(n) **API** and **Microservice.**

**API:**  a set of subroutine definitions, communication protocols, and tools for building software. In general terms, it is a set of clearly defined methods of communication between various components.

**Microservice:** a software development technique—a variant of the service-oriented architecture (SOA) architectural style that structures an application as a collection of loosely coupled services. In a microservices architecture, services are fine-grained and the protocols are lightweight.

`Now, the answer to your question:`

Anything, that you deploy on Azure Service Fabric does not by default becomes a micro service. It completely depends on how your usecase is divided into multiple individual and independent components which interact with each other or share data using accepted protocols and pre defined contracts.

Azure Service Fabric is a Platform as a Service (PaaS) offering designed to facilitate the development, deployment and management of highly scalable and customizable applications for the Microsoft Azure cloud platform.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1: Depends on what the service does. There is nothing inherent in the technology that makes a service a microservice. You basically ask "if my car has 4 wheels, is it classified as a taxi".

Scenario 2: Same as Scenario 1. It could as well be a full service.

Comment: Downvoter, you may want to [complain to Wikipedia for its entry on Microservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices).  Anyone who knows what Microservices really are understands this is the only answer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well I suspect the downvoter was more interested in the fact that this entire answer can be summed up as "it depends". Not worth an upvote though imo.

Comment: @DavidG the problem is that the question itself asks the wrong things. It's not even the OP's fault, it's due to the marketing hype that wants everything to be a "microservice"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Indeed, which is why I voted to close the question but didn't downvote that either.